# C structure for Graph, help understanding the structure

Tags: c, graph

I'm trying to create a data structure in C to represent graph. I found this very useful link:

http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/C/Graphs

It seems to me a quite good starting point. But I have some problem understanding the data structure.

```
struct graph {
    int n;              /* number of vertices */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    struct successors {
        int d;          /* number of successors */
        int len;        /* number of slots in array */
        char is_sorted; /* true if list is already sorted */
        int list[1];    /* actual list of successors */
    } *alist[1];
};
```

I can't understand why the struct successor is declared as it is and not in this way:

```
struct graph {
    int n;              /* number of vertices */
    int m;              /* number of edges */
    struct successors {
        int d;          /* number of successors */
        int len;        /* number of slots in array */
        char is_sorted; /* true if list is already sorted */
        int *list;    /* actual list of successors */
    } *alist;
};
```

As I can see in the sequent function to create the graph:

```
Graph
graph_create(int n)
{
    Graph g;
    int i;

    g = malloc(sizeof(struct graph) + sizeof(struct successors *) * (n-1));
    assert(g);

    g->n = n;
    g->m = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        g->alist[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct successors));
        assert(g->alist[i]);

        g->alist[i]->d = 0;
        g->alist[i]->len = 1;
        g->alist[i]->is_sorted= 1;
    }

    return g;
}
```

It allocates more spaces for alist and I can't understand why declare it as alist[1].
Can you please explain me how this works?

I hope the question is clear, because I'm quite confused myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 struct successors {
     /*
     */
     int list[1];    /* actual list of successors */
 } *alist[1];
```

Uses double indirection (each pointer op `*`/`&` and the subscript operator `[]` is a level of indirection and requires an additional memory access) on the `alist` member to enable each index to be `malloc`'d.

```
struct successors {
     /*
     */
    int *list;    /* actual list of successors */
} *alist;
```

Does not.

Also, from your link:

```
 /* basic directed graph type */
 typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

That link has quite a lot of code.

I don't fully understand how `->list` is used but your approach only reserves space for `int *` while the original reserves both the pointer and the target `int`.

The allocation of

```
g = malloc(sizeof(struct graph) + sizeof(struct successors *) * (n-1));
```

only allocs `successors *` so each `successors` object can (in theory) be crudely extended to point to more `int`'s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please be more verbose? I didn't get this thing of 'double indirection'.